# Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout (WebView in a ViewPager)

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-webview, android-viewpager

I will update a full tutorial later on how to implement a `WebView` inside a `ViewPager`, but I am getting a really weird issue that I don't understand how to fix.

Here are the implementations I'm running...

XML:

```
     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
     android:id="@+id/viewpager"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_above="@+id/lastLoginText"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/PreferencesButton" >

     </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

ViewPager Instantiate Object:

```
((ViewPager) collection).removeAllViews();
WebView a = webview[position];
((ViewPager) collection).addView(a);
```

Webviews are setup in a separate (InitWebViews)

```
    webview[0] = new WebView(this.getApplicationContext());
    webview[0].loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
    webview[1] = new WebView(this.getApplicationContext());
    webview[1].loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
    webview[2] = new WebView(this.getApplicationContext());
    webview[2].loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
```

Any ideas why it'd be like this, or how I can force the `viewWidth` to be 1280?  Or are there any other issues with the way I init the `WebView`s?

Comment: And the question is? You should put the question clearly some where. Right now some of the question is in title and some at the bottom in text. Very confusing.